# Mean Variance Investment problem

Tags: finance, modern-portfolio-theory

I attach a part of a paper explaining how the weights of a market portfolio are derived. I do not understand how equation 5 has been derived and, in particular, where the zero beta portfolio's return comes from.
Many thanks in advance

[image]

For the curious, this is an excerpt from *Capital Asset Pricing Compatible with Observed Market Value Weights*
by Michael J. Best and Robert R. Graber,
The Journal of Finance,  Vol. 40, No. 1 (Mar., 1985), pp. 85-103

Comment: All portfolios on the fromtier can be written as a linear combination of two portfolios on the frontier. Here the two base portfolios are:(1)The market portfolio, (2)The Zero Beta portfolio, which is by definition the portfolio orthogonal to the market portfolio. That is why $\bar{r}_Z$ enters into the equation. It plays a role similar to the risk free rate in the CAPM. You may want to look up Orthogonal Portfolios and zero beta portfolio . Or the 4 references given.

Comment: This looks the classic derivation of the MaxSharpe portfolio. See pp.23-24 in http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfolioTheoryMatrix.pdf

Answer (score 2):

you can observe that if:

$$ \Sigma x + \lambda t = s \mu $$

then:

$$ x = \Sigma^{-1}su - \Sigma^{-1}\lambda t $$

satisfies this. This is of a similar form to (5) without explicit constants.

Then,

$$ t'x=1 $$

gives

$$ t'\Sigma^{-1}su - t '\Sigma^{-1}\lambda t = 1 $$

So $ \lambda = \frac{s t' \Sigma^{-1} u - 1}{t' \Sigma^{-1} t} $

Now that you have $x$ in terms of $u$ and $s$ I suppose it is substituted back into (2) and solved as a 1-dim maximisation problem for parameter s. The above formula essentially finds the efficient frontier and the precise optimal efficient portfoli0 depends on the risk free rate $r_f$.

Anyway, this was a quick 5 minute job, sorry I didn't manage to get the full answer. hope it helps.